# Excel - Not to copy entire row just rows from Colum E to K to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I found this Excel VBA code that's very short and clean and it does its job to copy the entire row based on a condition. I added it to my vba project and it works well the only problem is - it copies the entire row.

I am trying to implement the code to only copy rows from Column E to K, but 
I have not been successful in tweaking the code to what I am trying to do.

Basically, in worksheet "verification" if Column "AB" = "Final" then copy each row that has "Final" from Column E to K to the worksheet "upload".

I am pulling my hair to make it work, and I have search everywehre and no luck. I know in this platform, I can find the solution to my problem. 
I will keep on playing with the code.

```
Sub CopyEachRowtoUpload()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long, a As Long, b As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set wsI = Sheets("Verification")
Set wsO = Sheets("Upload")

Set rng = wsI.Range("E:K")

'Last Row in a Column. Row need to start in row 2
LastRow = wsI.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

'Last Column in a Row. Rows from Column E to K is what I want to copy
LastColumn = wsI.Cells(5, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Row start

j = 2

With wsI
   'Loop through each row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If Range("AB" & i).Value = "Final" Then
            wsI.Rows(i).Copy
            wsO.Rows(j).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        j = j + 1   
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Replace `wsI.Rows(i).Copy` with `wsI.Range("E" & i & ":K" & i).Copy` This says: copy columns E through K on the current row instead of the entire row.

Comment: You might also want to change your paste range to something like `wsO.Cells(j, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` - `A` is the column you want to paste the data to

Comment: You are the man. Thank you so much. it works!!!

Comment: Thanks once again. I made the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) together with the [Range.Resize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to locate and shape the source and target.

```
With wsI
    'Loop through each row
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        If .Range("AB" & i).Value = "Final" Then
            wsO.Cells(j, "A").Resize(1, 7) = .Cells(i, "E").Resize(1, 7).Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Direct value transfer is preferred over Copy, Paste Special, Values if all you want is the cell values.

btw, you were missing a `.` in `.Range("AB" & i).Value`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this extra add in. Greatly appreciate everyone in this community platform.